# Why is "ser" and not "estar" used for expressing the current time?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, cópulas, expresiones

As an example, if I wanted to say "it's 5:00," I would say

> Son las cinco.

Why is this not the following?

> Están las cinco.

As far as I know, *ser* is used for permanent / inherent qualities, which the current time is not. The current time is temporary (because it's always changing), so the verb should be *estar*. Right?

Comment: Please try to avoid thinking of *ser* as permanent and *estar* as temporary. You will be much happier when you break past that :-)

Comment: Time is not mutable, even though it makes everything else mutable. But I'm with those who say it's best not to get too philosophical about word usages.

Comment: @guifa Thanks, but what should I think instead, then?

Comment: @Doorknob essence/identity (ser) vs state/condition (estar) will cover a lot more bases.  I only have recently added identity in there for my students because when you identify a noun as being another noun, you can only use ser since estar can't ever take nouns)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those expressions that you should not try to translate from a language to another.

You are not actually asking about the time, but about the *hour*. That `What time is it?` is sort of `Which is the hour?` when asked in Spanish, so you are identifying one of the 24 moments in which we have divided the day. We are not identifying a property of time, but one segment of the day.

The same way we don't say `qué es tu nombre` si no `cómo te llamas` for `what is your name` we don't ask `what time is it?` as you do in English but sort of `which is the hour?` or `which is that moment of the day?`.

We also say that

> **Era** por la mañana cuando me encontré con Pablo.
>
> **Es** a mediodía cuando el sol está mas alto y cuando oscurece es porque **es** de noche.
>
> Ahora **es** de noche.

We are picking between the segments in which we divided the day, not a property that happened to the day.

The only time you would hear that the *tiempo está* is to talk or ask about weather, not time, and for the reason you said (mutability).